# imap чтение отправленных писем

Tags: php, imap

Видел полно примеров, в том числе и функции самой библы imap как читать входящие письма.
А как получить отправленные письма?

Comment: [Как написано в руководстве](https://php.net/manual/ru/book.imap.php)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получать отправленные электронные письма, их нужно сохранить. Доставкой и доступом к ящику занимаются две разные службы, работающие через разные протоколы. Например, пожалуй чаще всего сейчас, доставка (отправка) идет по протоколу SMTP, а доступ к письмам в ящике через протокол IMAP.

При отправке через SMTP (или после отправки) служба доставки может сохранять отправленные письма в одной из IMAP-папок (например Sent или в любой другой - это на совести почтового администратора) или это может сделать почтовый клиент (Outlook, Thunderbird и т. д.). Но этого может и не быть вообще. Поэтому ответ на ваш вопрос в первую очередь зависит от другого вопроса: Сохраняет-ли ваш сервис доставки отправленную почту и если да, то как и где?

Answer (score 0):

```
$mbox = imap_open("{example,com:143}Sent mail", $user, $pass);
```

?