# Как получить список исходящей почты mail.ru через php

Tags: php, imap, mail.ru

Товарисчи.
Имеется ящик на mail.ru
С помощью imap_open успешно подключаюсь к imap.mail.ru и тащу список входящих сообщений.
Вопрос в том, как можно получить список исходящих сообщений?
UPD:
В общем, кому интересно, mail.ru исходящие сообщения хранит в папке "Отправленное". Именно так, русскими буквами и надо писать вместо INBOX.

Пример:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$host        = 'imap.mail.ru';
$port        =  993;
$login       = 'yourmail@domen.com';
$pass        = 'pass';
$param       = '/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert';
$folder      = 'Отправленное';
if($mbox = imap_open("{"."{$host}:{$port}{$param}"."}$folder",$login,$pass)){
echo "Connectedn";
} else { exit ("Can't connect: " . imap_last_error() ."n");echo"FAIL!n";  };?>
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420709/imap-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC